# How to answer 'yes' automatically to prompts in a recursive powershell loop?

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell, prompt

I have this block that I use to resize videos in nested subfolders with `ffmpeg` and then delete the original

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 -Recurse | % { ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -vf "scale='if(gt(ih,iw),360,-2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),360,-2)'" "$($_.FullName)_scaled.mp4" && Remove-Item $_.FullName }
```

I have ran this a few times with interruptions so I would get prompted to overwrite files on subsequent runs. Is there an actual way to make the script overwrite existing files automatically?

I tried adding `echo y |` in front of the whole script and it just kind of hangs for a bit then nothing happens

I also tried adding `-Force` at the end of each loop like this eg. [...] `&& Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force}` and I still get a y/n prompt

How do I do it?

Comment: Is there a change if you add the `-y` flag to ffmpeg?  Ex:  `ffmpeg -y -i $_.FullNa.....`  --  `-y` is the global variable for "overwrite without asking" https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

Answer (score 1):

For `Remove-Item` not to prompt, add the following parameters:

```
-Force -Confirm:$false
```

Reference :
[How can I delete files with PowerShell without confirmation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611350/how-can-i-delete-files-with-powershell-without-confirmation)